# Is it possible to change the text of selected item in a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown in which I am displaying items as below:

1             Apple 
2              Banana
3              Mango
4              Orange

Now when I select any option, I just want the Number to be displayed not the entire item text. i.e when I select "1    Apple", I just want "1" to be displayed. How do I achieve this?

I've tried changing the text using

```
 $("#ddlFruits option:selected").text($("#ddlFruits option:selected").text().split(' ')[0])
```

but this also changes the item in dropdown.

Comment: Do you want the text to return if changing the selected option? Or do you want it so that once you make a choice, the text is gone forever and only the number remains?

Comment: I want the text to return when trying to change the selected option again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only display the number when an option is selected, but keep the number and text when making a change, use a change and mousedown combination of events

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  option = $(this).val().split(' ')
  $('option:selected', this).data('orig', $(this).val()).html(option[0])
}).mousedown(function() {
  $('select option').each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).data('orig'))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1 Apple </option>
  <option>2 Banana</option>
  <option>3 Mango</option>
  <option>4 Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just FYI this is broken if you select the same option twice

Answer (score 0):

`select`-elements have a `selectedIndex`-property that you could use in the `change`-event to get the selected option and manipulate its value or innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that the select's value has changed, and in that case, you will have the information of which option has been selected.

Then two things must happen: first you need to make sure that all options return to its original state (where they display the full label), this is because you are going to modify those labels. Secondly, you will go ahead and update the selected option's label simply by selecting the first portion of its value (I choose value just for convenience, but it can very well be the text of the option or an external source).

**note that in order to properly split the value of the option, I have to pass in a white space as a parameter to the split function.**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddlFruits").on('change', function() {
    var $selected = $('option:selected', this);
        $notSelected = $('option:not(:selected)', this);
        
        $notSelected.each(function(i, option) {
          $(option).text( $(option).val() );
        });
        $selected.text( $selected.val().split(' ')[0] );

  })  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ddlFruits" id="ddlFruits">
  <option value="1 Apple">1 Apple</option>
  <option value="2 Banana">2 Banana</option>
  <option value="3 Mango">3 Mango</option>
</select>
```